# Generating SQL from migrations without drop-all

Tags: grails, grails-orm, database-migration, liquibase

Say I have 3 commits (each one with new migrations added):

- v3 (add new column)
- v2 (add new table)
- v1

Production database is at `v1` and my development database is at `v3`.

I want to generate an SQL script which will upgrade the production database to `v3`.

The only way I know how to do so is to rollback development database to `v1` (by checking out `v1` and running `dbm-rollback`) and then checkout `v3` and run `dbm-update-sql`.

Is there a way to do this without rolling the development database back (or hacking away at the `DATABASECHANGELOG` table)? Something like `dbm-update-count-sql 2` which would create the SQL for the last two migrations regardless of whether they have already been run in development.

EDIT: cannot connect to the prod database from the development machine

Answer (score 1):

If you are using updateSQL to generate the SQL, Liquibase makes no change to the database you are pointing it at, it just generates what it would execute on a normal update. So, the easiest option would be to just run updateSQL against your production database to get the script needed to update it.

If that does not work for you, if you are able to backup/restore the DATABASECHANGELOG table to another database (even an otherwise blank database) and run updateSQL against that, it will output the same SQL.

Finally, you can use ["offline mode"](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/offline.html) to use a CSV file to act as the DATABASECHANGELOG table when running updateSQL. Running with an empty table will generate all update SQL, but if you include just the changes in the file that are in production, updateSQL will output just what is needed to update production.

Answer (score 0):

If you can connect to the production database, you would just run liquibase with the updateSQL command.

Comment: cannot connect to prod database :(